# Restricting post method and authentication to specifc URL paths in Apache .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

I shall start with an example. I want to restrict to POST requests only for `http://path/to/logical/abc.xml` and restrict to GET only for `http://path/to/logical/def.xml`. How do I put constraints like this as the paths are logical and location directive is not supported in *.htaccess*?

The actual problem is to set different authentication constraint on diff logical file. Can you tell me as to how do I put  a constraint on logical path in the *.htaccess* file as location directive is not supported in *.htaccess*.

Comment: What do you mean by "[the] location directive is not supported in .htaccess"? Are you referring to the `Location:` HTTP request header?

Comment: I was refering to the location directive of apache `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can probably do this by checking against `THE_REQUEST` in a `RewriteCond` (mod_rewrite) directive in .htaccess.

```
http://example.com/path/to/logical/abc.xml - POST only  
http://example.com/path/to/logical/def.xml - GET ONLY
```

For our POST only URL, if the request is not a POST request then reject (403 - Forbidden).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${THE_REQUEST} !^POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/logical/abc.xml - [F]
```

For our GET only URL, if the request is not a GET request then reject (403 - Forbidden).

```
RewriteCond ${THE_REQUEST} !^GET [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/logical/def.xml - [F]
```

(Not tested)

Comment: Bunch of Thanks for the reply. I tried this out and works fine I used regex and could filter only the file without appending the logical path to it . `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteCond ${THE_REQUEST} !^GET [NC]` `RewriteRule ^(.*)/Filename.xml -[F]`. Instead of sending the forbidden I would like to authenticate my abc.xml for basic type of authentication and def for digest type of authentication . How can I do that ?? Can you provide some ideas on that aspect. I am working on Apache 2.2 version